# How filter input for Farsi character?

Tags: php, regex

I want filter input just for Farsi, i think regular expression with `filter_input()` is a good idea but 
i dont know how solve this problem, I've search but i don't find sth like \p{Arabic} for Farsi or Persian character in the other hand it can be possible with [Unicode](http://www.tamasoft.co.jp/en/general-info/unicode.html) but i've no idea about its regular expression.

Comment: Have you tried `\p{Arabic}` and see if it works? `Arabic` refers to the script (which includes different Unicode blocks) for languages that uses Arabic scripts.

Comment: No because Persia has 4 more character than Arabic has.

Comment: I mean the Unicode Arabic script, not the Arabic language or Persian language itself. The language may have different, but does the Unicode Arabic script support everything? (Try to type it out here: http://www.regex101.com/r/tZ9dB4). If it does not match, can you show the example?

Comment: thanks this site is very awesome i tested and its work for persian but when i test it in PHP it doesn't work at all,

Comment: $text = 'ads';   
$regex = '/^\p{Arabic}+$/';    

$itFoundMatch = preg_match( $regex, $text );   //$itFoundMatch == false

Comment: `ads` is not even Persian script!

Comment: yes it is not this is a example because  when i write sth like "سیب" (means apple) php convert it to Ø³ÛŒØ¨ i still don't know how use it. i want get text from the user and check it whether is Persia or English.

Comment: How do you take in user input? (Edit your question, please).

Comment: this question is solved by you, thanks. but i have another problem with php assign. I'm going to take the text with form's field and post it to process page so that validation it with filter_input() method but php ignore Arabic font in its variable.

Comment: Without any code, I don't know where to start answering your question.

Comment: this problem solved but when i want echo "فارسی"; php shows sth like  Ø³ÛŒØ¨

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This should work :

`preg_match("(^[\x{0600}-\x{06FF}]*$)", 'فارسی');`

And also you can use all these forms for Persian language :

**Persian Alphabet**

> فارسی

```
/^([\x{0600}-\x{06EF}])+$/
```

**Persian Numbers**

> ۱۲۳۴۵۶۷۸۹۰

```
/^([\x{06F0}-\x{06F9}])+$/
```

**Persian simple text with space and half-space**

> اگر زمان و مکان در اختیار ما بود، ۱۰ سال پیش از طوفان نوح عاشقت می‌شدم

```
/^([\x{0600}-\x{06FF}| |\x{200C}])+$/
```

- [ref](http://php.net/manual/de/function.preg-match.php)

Comment: this problem solved but how can i show the result something like echo "فارسی";

Comment: preg_match just checks if expression is in 0600 and 06FF then tell you it's true or not, you mean you can't print 'فارسی' in html page?

Comment: preg_match returns 1 that indicates success but when i want print Arabic string php prints weird character  sth like Ø³ÛŒØ¨

Comment: the problem is in your document Encoding, your document should be saved in UTF-8 without boom, you can use notepad++ or sublime text and in file menu change document encoding, and then you should define UTF-8 in your html page meta data, Just paste this in your html header : `<meta charset="UTF-8">`

Comment: yeah :) you're right that's it, thanks about your helping so my problem is about Encoding. thanks all of you guys.

Comment: What is the last `\x` in `[\x{0600}-\x{06FF}\x]`? I don't understand what it really does.

Comment: Oops! there was a mistake on my regular expression, you right @MohammadNaji i updated expression.