# Android simple JSONArray search using JsonPath

Tags: java, android, jsonpath

Here is a sample JSONArray in which I am trying to search using JsonPath:

```
["ح م د","ر ب ب","ع ل م","ر ح م","م ل ک","ی و م","د ی ن","ع ب د","ع ون","ع ون","س ف ہ","س ف ہ"]
```

Its an array of Arabic characters. I am trying to search for value that begins with specific character, for eg. س (seen)

I am using JsonPath like this:

```
JsonPath.read(myJSONArray.toString(), "$[*][?(@ =~ /^س/i)]", null);
```

Its returning 0, whereas it should return 2 values as per the sample data. Any idea why the expression not working?

**Note:** My actual JSONArray includes records in 1000s. So if you think there is better approach than to use JsonPath java library, then your suggestion are most welcome. :)

Comment: have you verified your regex? maybe use an external regex-checker?

Comment: @MartinFrank I have tried on regex101.com without using ^ and its working but in Java its still returning 0

Comment: I am in doubt in XPath expression but the documentation at https://github.com/jayway/JsonPath is for JSONObject with Array, mine is simple JSONArray.

Comment: you have to add unicode encoding while searching arabic . See http://stackoverflow.com/a/15203555/3496570

Comment: I have further experimented on XPath Java library and it seems to only work with JSONObjects, simple JSONArray doesn't support regex.